# Group by a variable in dataframe R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like below,

| Date | cat | cam | reg | per |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22-01-05 | A | 60 | 120 | 50 |
| 22-01-05 | B | 20 | 100 | 20 |
| 22-01-08 | A | 30 | 150 | 20 |
| 22-01-08 | B | 30 | 100 | 30 |

But i want something like below,

| Date | cam | reg | per |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22-01-05 | 80 | 220 | 14.5 |
| 22-01-08 | 60 | 250 | 24 |

How to get this using R?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Comment: If i use this i will end up with the sum of `per` column too. That's not what i want here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why your expected `per` values are like that, but maybe you want the following:

```r
df <- data.frame(Date = c("22-01-05", "22-01-05", "22-01-08", "22-01-08"),
                 cat = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
                 cam = c(60,20,30,30),
                 reg = c(120,100,150,100),
                 per = c(50,20,20,30))

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  summarise(cam = sum(cam),
            reg = sum(reg),
            per = cam/reg)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   Date       cam   reg   per
#>   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 22-01-05    80   220 0.364
#> 2 22-01-08    60   250 0.24
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: `per` is derived by cam/reg. This aggregation using sum function gets the sum of per too. That's why asked this question to get the answer for deriving as expected.

Comment: @learner, I updated my answer, is this what you mean?

Comment: If i want to pass the cam, reg and per column names to a function to do this aggregation, how to write a function for that? Could you please help me

Answer (score 2):

Using only the package `dplyr` (which is part of package `tidyverse`) just do:

```
df %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarise(cam  = sum(cam),
                                reg = sum(reg),
                                per = 100*(cam/reg))

Date       cam   reg   per
<chr>    <int> <int> <dbl>
1 22-01-05    80   220  36.4
2 22-01-08    60   250  24
```

The nice thing with this syntax is, you can modify and add additional variables like sum, but also like mean, median, etc. in a very clean and structured way.

Answer (score 1):

> you can try this, but I don't how to get the value of per ,14.5 and 24

```
  library(dplyr)
 aggregate(cbind(cam, reg) ~ Date,df,sum) %>% mutate(per = 100*(cam/reg))
 A data.frame: 2 × 4
Date    cam      reg    per
<chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
22-01-05    80   220    36.36364
22-01-08    60   250     24.00000
```